# Deployment of Angular JS project having rest calls

Tags: angularjs, apache, deployment

I am new to Angular Js. Following in my scenario.

I have static website.(i.e. pure html pages) deployed on godaddy.
I am developing Angular Js applications.
Angular is calling rest api developed in java.
I have taken aws vpc and deploying rest api on two Wildfly 9.0 server and apache 2.4 as load balancer.

Now I have confusion where to deploy Angular js app.

1. Whether I should deploy it on godaddy along with my static site(Merge both of them into one).
2. Whether I should deploy my static site and angular js app (again merge) on apache in aws vpc.
3. Whether I should deploy angular js app on wildfly server.

Need your suggestion which scenario will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a static site, you can put it into a S3 bucket and not have to worry about the hassle of a server. This way you don't have to worry about the size of the server or load balancing.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: Thanks Brent for the answer. You mean I keep everything ie static site and my angular js app on S3 bucket. However in this case I will have to enable cors on my server.